# C/C++ Little/Big Endian handler

Tags: c++, c, endianness

There are two systems that communicate via TCP. One uses little endian and the second one big endian. The ICD between systems contains a lot of structs (fields). Making bytes swap for each field looks like not the best solution.

Is there any generic solution/practice for handling communication between systems with different endianness?

Comment: C and C++ are two completely different languages, you have to chose one.

Comment: "looks like not the best solution" Unfortunately you might find out there are no better solutions. Sometimes you need to roll up your sleeves and get your hands a bit dirty.

Comment: You don't have to solve this yourself, use an RPC mechanism like gRPC to transfer your data, it will avoid a lot of other issues as wel (alignment, buffer sizes etc). Introduction here : https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/

Comment: @Fareanor: If you've got two systems communicating, you don't have to chose one ;) Seriously: this is a question on protocol design, and the two language tags imply that we can't use a language built-in (such as Python pickle)

Comment: @MSalters it’s true this can be done in multiple languages but you should know people spam c and c++ tags as if they are the same language. If you want a c and a c++ solution, you should say that. If you want a c _or_ c++ solution, you should say that. But c/c++ is not a language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, values transmitted over a network should be in *network byte order*, i.e. big endian.  So values should be converted from host byte order to network byte order for transmission and converted back when received.

The functions `htons` and `ntohs` do this for 16 bit integer values and `htonl` and `ntohl` do this for 32 bit integer values.  On little endian systems these functions essentially reverse the bytes, while on big endian systems they're a no-op.

So for example if you have the following struct:

```
struct mystruct {
    char f1[10];
    uint32_t f2;
    uint16_t f3;
};
```

Then you would serialize the data like this:

```c
// s points to the struct to serialize
// p should be large enough to hold the serialized struct
void serialize(struct mystruct *s, unsigned char *p)
{
    memcpy(p, s->f1, sizeof(s->f1));
    p += sizeof(s->f1);

    uint32_t f2_tmp = htonl(s->f2);
    memcpy(p, &f2_tmp, sizeof(f2_tmp));
    p += sizeof(s->f2);

    uint16_t f3_tmp = htons(s->f3);
    memcpy(p, &f3_tmp, sizeof(f3_tmp));
}
```

And deserialize it like this:

```c
// s points to a struct which will store the deserialized data
// p points to the buffer received from the network
void deserialize(struct mystruct *s, unsigned char *p)
{
    memcpy(s->f1, p, sizeof(s->f1));
    p += sizeof(s->f1);

    uint32_t f2_tmp;
    memcpy(&f2_tmp, p, sizeof(f2_tmp));
    s->f2 = ntohl(f2_tmp);
    p += sizeof(s->f2);

    uint16_t f3_tmp;
    memcpy(&f3_tmp, p, sizeof(f3_tmp));
    s->f3 = ntohs(f3_tmp);
}
```

While you *could* use compiler specific flags to pack the struct so that it has a known size, allowing you to `memcpy` the whole struct and just convert the integer fields, doing so means that certain fields may not be aligned properly which can be a problem on some architectures.  The above will work regardless of the overall size of the struct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned, I don't want to convert each filed. I'm looking for some generic solution.

Comment: @Droll80 Unfortunately, that's what you're stuck with.  The data needs to be in a known format going over the wire, so you need to do whatever is necessary to make that happen.

Comment: "data needs to be in a known format" - I understand this)) I'm looking for the way to do this. Go over all structs/fileds (~ 20 messages with ~200 fileds in each) and add swap function for each isn't looked like a good idea.

Comment: thanks for adding example. Now I got what you meant. For now, it looks like the best solution. Thanks again

Comment: One can use packed structs and avoid malloc/memcpy:  struct mystruct { ... } __attribute__ ((packed)) ;

Comment: @ulix have never used this attribute. Looks like a promising idea. I would like to avoid using malloc in embedded system.

Comment: @ulix That won't change the CPU's need for aligned access though. Structs have members aligned for a reason.

Comment: @dbush You probably meant to also store those f2_tmp, f3_tmp inside the struct before returning it, yeah?

Comment: Benchmarking: https://godbolt.org/z/Kvbc3bW89. Using `ntohl` gave identical machine code as portable bit-shifts. So we can use either, if we for example want to write non-portable code just for the heck of it.

Comment: Stop trying to beat the compiler until you’ve actually identified an area where it fails to optimize under -o2 or -o3. It knows better tricks than you. And you make it’s job harder when you try to shortcut it.

Comment: @Lundin Correct, fixed.  Also updated to allow the caller to pass in the destination buffer.

Answer (score 10):

Each system may have a different architecture, but endianness should be defined by the communication protocol. If the protocol says "data must be sent as big endian", then that's how the system sends it and how the other system receives it.

I am guessing the reason why you're asking is because you would like to cast a struct pointer to a `char*` and just send it over the wire, and this won't work.

That is generally a bad idea. It's far better to create an actual serializer, so that your internal data is decoupled from the actual protocol, which also means you can easily add support for different protocols in the future, or different versions of the protocols. You also don't have to worry about struct padding, aliasing, or any implementation-defined issues that casting brings along.

**(update)**

So generally, you would have something like:

```
void Serialize(const struct SomeStruct *s, struct BufferBuilder *bb)
{
    BufferBuilder_append_u16_le(bb, s->SomeField);
    BufferBuilder_append_s32_le(bb, s->SomeOther);
    
    ...
    
    BufferBuilder_append_u08(bb, s->SomeOther);
}
```

Where you would already have all these methods written in advance, like

```
// append unsigned 16-bit value, little endian
void BufferBuilder_append_u16_le(struct BufferBuilder *bb, uint16_t value)
{
    if (bb->remaining < sizeof(value))
    {
        return; // or some error handling, whatever
    } 
    
    memcpy(bb->buffer, &value, sizeof(value));
    bb->remaining -= sizeof(value);
}
```

We use this approach because it's simpler to unit test these "appending" methods in isolation, and writing (de)serializers is then a matter of just calling them in succession.

But of course, if you can pick any protocol and implement both systems, then you could simply use protobuf and avoid doing a bunch of plumbing.

Comment: You are 100% right. I want to fill struct, take pointer, and send it. And vise verse, get data as pointer and make memcpy to relevant struct. May you give please an example of serializer you mentioned?

Comment: @Droll80: Endianness is one of the multiple reasons why that does not work. Offsets of fields in structures isn't defined by C or C++ either (and C++ breaks the one weak guarantee that C had, about member _order_). Heck even `sizeof(long)` is not standard.

Comment: @Droll80: As for serializers that do work, have a peek at things like ProtoBuf.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the commend, @dbush added an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73895788/69809) already. One difference that I would make is that, instead of allocating the buffer inside the serialize method, we pass the buffer into the method (and this buffer is actually inside a struct which also contains the buffer remaining length, so we have some handy methods to write to check if there is enough space, write to the buffer and decrement remaining length).

Comment: Of course - as @MSalters wrote - if you control both systems and you get to pick the protocol, then a standard solution like protobuf would be a no brainer. It's fast, efficient, portable and ported to pretty much all programming languages.

Comment: @MSalters ProtoBuf is a good idea but, I cannot add its libs to the project...

Comment: @Droll80: so basically dbush wrote a great example below, I updated my answer with some ideas that I used in my projects to make the serializers a bit more readable and less prone to buffer overruns.

Comment: @MSalters what you think about this:  **#pragma scalar_storage_order big-endian** ?

Answer (score 0):

You mention one problem with struct fields. Transmitting `struct`s also requires taking care of alignment of fields (causing gaps between fields): compiler flags.

For binary data one can use [**Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) where you define the data format. There are some alternatives. Like [**Protocol Buffers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers).

In C one can with macros determine endianess and field offsets inside a struct, and hence use such a struct description as the basis for a generic *bytes-to-struct* conversion. So this would work independent of endianess and alignment.

You would need to create such a descriptor for every struct.

Alternatively a parser might generate code for bytes-to-struct conversion.

But then again you could use a language neutral solution like ASN.1.

C and C++ of course have no introspection/reflection capabilities like Java has, so that are the only solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use #pragma pack(push, 1) for alignment my structs. Am I understand you right?

Comment: Yes, precise, then structs are packed. Of course the generated assembly when addressing an int field might then be suboptimal; there is a reason for aligning fields. Thanks for mentioning the **#pragma pack**.

Answer (score -1):

**The fastest and most portable way is to use bit shifts.**
These have the big advantage that you only need to know the network endianess, never the CPU endianess.

Example:

```c
uint8_t  buf[4] = { MS_BYTE, ... LS_BYTE}; // some buffer from TCP/IP = Big Endian
uint32_t my_u32 = ((uint32_t)buf[0] << 24) |
                  ((uint32_t)buf[1] << 16) |
                  ((uint32_t)buf[2] <<  8) |
                  ((uint32_t)buf[3] <<  0) ;
```

- **Do not use (bit-field) structs/type punning directly on the input.** They are poorly standardized, may contain padding/alignment requirements, depend on endianess. It is fine to use structs if you have proper serialization/deserialization routines in between. A deserialization routine may contain the above bit shifts, for example.
- **Do not use pointer arithmetic to iterate across the input, or plain memcpy()**. Neither one of these solves the endianess issue.
- **Do not use `htons` etc bloat libs.** Because they are non-portable. But more importantly because anyone who can't write a simple bit shift like above without having some lib function holding their hand, should probably stick to writing high level code in a more family-friendly programming language.

  There is no point in writing code in C if you don't have a clue about how to do efficient, close to the hardware programming, also known as the very reason you picked C for the task to begin with.

**EDIT**
Helping hand for people who are confused over how C code gets translated to asm: https://godbolt.org/z/TT1MP7oc4. As we can see, the machine code is identical on x86 Linux. The `htonl` won't compile on a number of embedded targets, nor on MSVC, while leading to worse performance on Mips64.

Comment: So, basically you say reimplement standard functionality, using an inefficient swap-in-place when the standard `htonl` is a no-op.  And you claim that's the "fastest". I'm not going to downvote a working answer, but this isn't a particularly good answer.

Comment: @MSalters First of all, I wouldn't use a function for utterly basic things, for the same reason as I write `a = b;` and not `a = assign(b);`.

Comment: Second, `htonl` etc are _not_ standard, they are barely even POSIX. *nix programmers tend to have this arrogant mentality than everything that is *nix is automatically standard - which is not true. These functions in some `#include <herpa/derpa.h>` are _not_ available on any embedded system. I'm not sure if they are even available in POSIX.

Comment: Third, `hton*` takes words or dwords as input, what if I have a raw byte buffer, which is very bloody likely? Strict aliasing violation or add an extra memcpy bloat?

Comment: Forth, `hton*` is also leading to worse performance on some systems. On the x86 64 flavours either version boils down to a single `bswap` but on mips64 (gcc -O3) the function version gives worse performance. https://godbolt.org/z/aYKbzj98c

Comment: @Lundin actually I'm working on INTEGRITY OS and do you use htonl and htos for configuring socket. These functions under <netconfig.h> header.

Comment: @MSalters And that would be 4 solid arguments against using this slow, non-standard function. Do you have any in favour of it?

Comment: @Droll80 And what if my network is UART or CAN etc, also with big network endianess?

Comment: @Lundin I don't know)) I'm looking for solution a best solution))

Comment: @Lundin: Well, I **have** a CAN device here, without an OS but with a Cortex-M microcontroller. Still uses `htons`.

Comment: @MSalters Well congrats, then you can write non-portable code just for the heck of it, instead of using portable bit-shifts resulting in 100% identical machine code...

Comment: I think we should agree that this is not a discussion about "how to swap bytes". I'm sure every one of us can do this in million + 1 method. I wanted to get some clues about different ways of serialization/deserialization. And @MSalters gave me a good idea of doing this. But Lundin just saw a basic byte reordering example.

Comment: @Droll80 In that case you are missing one of the main points made here, which is that bit shifts work the same no matter CPU endianess. So I could for example freely port the code between x86 and PowerPC. No need for extra libs, no need to consider CPU.

Comment: Portability is a myth. How many programs have you actually written for one system then had to port over to a completely different system and didn’t have to change a thing? Just taking in the biggest two targets, x86 windows and Linux, any decently sized codebase is FULL of platform specific defs to make the code work.

Comment: @Lundin you are right that your bytes swap code can be ported wherever you want. May you give me an advice/example of using your portable code related to my question? Not only 4 lines of swapping bytes?

Comment: @Taekahn "How many programs have you actually written for one system then had to port over to a completely different system and didn’t have to change a thing?" Portability should be written on the code module level. Porting whole programs as-is isn't something I do often, but porting individual modules, I do all the time. The most common use-case being "re-use parts of the code from the previous project". Done without having to change a thing - it's everyday C programming. Including porting  code modules between some evil 8-bit MCU in C and a 64 bit Windows PC running C+.

Comment: @Droll80 I made an example in comments below dbush's answer. https://godbolt.org/z/Kvbc3bW89. Struct serialization/deserializing isn't rocket science, it's just about filling up one struct member at a time. Ideally while fixing endianess at the same time.

Comment: Not only are `htonl()` and friends in POSIX, but they have *always* been in POSIX, inasmuch as they date back at least as far as SUS 2 (1997), a POSIX predecessor.  They do not even have any feature-test macro requirements. (Current POSIX spec: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html).  POSIX is a separate standard from C, and C implementations do not all conform to POSIX or provide these particular functions.  But relying on that to claim that `htonl()` and friends are not standard is misleading.

Comment: @JohnBollinger POSIX is completely irrelevant to a lot of applications using C, therefore something could be included in POSIX and still be non-portable. Also, POSIX is happy to include anything and everything that the cat dragged in, so just because something was included in POSIX doesn't mean that it's a sound function to use. Quite often it's the opposite...

Comment: I agree that POSIX standardization does not make anything *universally* portable, but that's a bit of a straw man.  No functions in the C standard library are portable in that sense either, because freestanding implementations don't need to provide them.  POSIX standardization does make things *widely* portable, often including even to platforms that don't fully conform to POSIX.  For example, Windows *does* provide the `htonl()` *etc*, though it declares them in [a different header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-htonl) than POSIX specifies.